# Can no longer drag/drop onto Storyboard after installing Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode4, storyboard, xcode5

I've installed Xcode 5 (currently in pre-release). Installing Xcode 5 does not overwrite Xcode 4. What's happening now is that when I open up my old projects in Xcode 4, I can no longer create new objects on the Storyboard by dragging and dropping GUI elements.

Has anyone experienced this?

** EDIT **

If you find yourself in the same situation. Simply reboot your computer.

I actually spent a good hour investigating this and sometimes, we're too stubborn to think that a simple reboot could fix the issue.

Comment: Reboot doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself in the same situation. Simply reboot your computer.

I actually spent a good hour investigating this and sometimes, even the best of us forget to try a reboot first.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember back to the first time you opened your Xcode 4 storyboard in Xcode 5, you were prompted with the following message.

[image]

The content of the above screenshot should answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I do remember that. I clicked Skip. I think I found out the answer to my problem though. I'll post in just a moment.